# How to combine customized MDI Text & Customized MDI Child Text on MDI's Title Bar?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have custom MDI Parent form and custom child form and I want to set title on mdi form it's own text + mdi child form's text when mdi child form is maximize. So how it possible?

[image]

Normal state of mdi child form it is work correctly.

[image]

In this image you can see form state is maximise but text of MDI child not shown with text of MDI Parent form.

Comment: Is this for Winforms ?

Comment: yes this is winforms

Comment: It is already working with that way? Doen't need to do anything extra.

Comment: Thanks Berkay, But MDI Parent form and MDI Child form both are border less or we can say with customised border.

Comment: **1)** Pleas add more details about what exactly you need. Also you should add more description about **Custom** MDI Parent and Child Form. What do you mean by custom forms?**2)** The default behavior is showing `Parent + Child Text` also you can handle `MdiChildActivate` for handling the text in cases the window in not maximized. What's your question exactly?

Comment: *1)* What's the difference between those images? *2)* what's expected result in Maximized or Normal state of window? *3)* Since you have custom forms, how can we assign new Text to your forms? It is simply `fooForm.Text="something new"`?

Comment: when mdi child form is maximize then text should be merge with text of MDI form. In image you can see I changed titlebar with default title bar so it is not working default way like MDI Parent Text + Mdi Child Text when MDI child is maximize. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: No problem. You can see the edit. You need to handle `Activated` and `SizeChanged` of child forms and  set the custom text this way: `this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { CustomText = this.Text; }));`

Comment: Pay attention that `SizeChanged` is not enough. You need to handle `Activated` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Form's `Size_Changed` event, (`Form1` is MDI parent, `TestForm` (frm) is MDI child)

```
TestForm frm;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     frm = new TestForm();
     frm.MdiParent = this;
     frm.SizeChanged += Frm_SizeChanged; 
     frm.Show();

}

private void Frm_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (frm.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized) { // checks Form's Window state and return true if it is maximized (mdi child's event btw)
          this.Text = this.Text + " " + frm.Text; // do what ever do you want in here
     }
}
```

Hope helps,

Comment: Thanks Berkay your code is work but issue is that frm_sizechanged event only (Child form is active) one time but I want to call that event when mdi child form is maximise.

Comment: What do you mean by one time? It tracks the size changing and condition looks for if it is maximized. @Hardik

Comment: Yes it is work thank you. I was made some mistake in code. again thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When you maximize an MDI child, the text of MDI container will be shown as:

```
ParentText - [ChildText]
```

So based on your edit I suppose you have a `CustomText` property like below:

```
private string CustomText
{
    get { return toolStripLabel1.Text; }
    set { toolStripLabel1.Text = value; }
}
```

Which shows a custom title-bar for form. Then if you have it acts like standard title-bar of form you can handle `Activated` and `SizeChanged` event of MDI child forms and set the `CustomText` using `BeginInvoke` this way:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var f = new Form2() { Text = "Form2" };
    f.MdiParent = this;
    f.Activated += new EventHandler(f_Activated);
    f.SizeChanged += new EventHandler(f_SizeChanged);
    f.Show();
}
void f_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { CustomText = this.Text; }));
}
void f_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { CustomText = this.Text; }));
}
```

**Note**

- [`MdiChildActivate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.mdichildactivate(v=vs.110).aspx) is useful to detect when an MDI child opens or closes.
- [`ActiveMdiChild`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activemdichild(v=vs.110).aspx) property shows you the active MDI child.

Comment: Thanks Reza Aghaei, This code is work for me but I want change text when mdi child form is maximise.

Comment: By default the Text of Parent + Text of Child will be shown in Maximized state.

Comment: this operation are performing with customise MDI Form and customise MDI Child form. That I mention in question.

Comment: So it's unclear what you are asking. The default behavior is showing `Parent + Child Text` also you can handle `MdiChildActivate` for handling the text in cases the window in not maximized. What's your question exactly?

Comment: I added two images for clear the question. See again question.